# Protractor and Cucumber: function timed out using async/await

Tags: angular, protractor, cucumber

I'm doing e2e and bdd tests using Angular 5, Protractor and Cucumber. When I run on terminal `ng e2e` I get the following error:

> When I open the page # e2e\steps\home.steps.ts:15
>
> Error: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 5000
>   milliseconds

In the line 15, I have:

```
 When(/^I open the page$/, async () => {
    await browser.get('http://localhost:49156');
 });
```

Specifically, it is the line:

```
 When(/^I open the page$/, async () => {
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The answer is very simple. By default, Cucumber takes 5000 ms for asynchronous hooks, but we can configure it by doing this:

```
When(/^I open the page$/, {timeout: 2 * 5000}, async () => {
```

It is even possible to configure it globally.

```
var {setDefaultTimeout} = require('cucumber');
setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);
```

More information: *[Timeouts](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/timeouts.md)*

Another thing: I configured the port badly. As you can see, I configured it on port 49156, because I had read that it was the default port, but it seems that has already changed and is now port 49152.

Comment: not working for me.. I want to run specific feature file in cucumber with angular 6 set up.I am using " protractor ./protractor.conf.js --specs='e2e/features/app.feature' " but it gives me error -   Error: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 5000 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Ricky's answer.

```
When(/^I open the page$/, {timeout: 2 * 5000}, async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000)); // wait for 5000 ms
})
```

Comment: There isn't anyone with the user name "Ricky" here. What does it refer to? [Luis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49862078/protractor-and-cucumber-function-timed-out-using-async-await/49862453#49862453)?

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber takes by default 5000 ms for asynchronous calls. We can modify this in the below-mentioned manner. This should go under the support directory in your framework for better practice.

Try using this:

```
const { setDefaultTimeout } = require('@cucumber/cucumber');
setDefaultTimeout(parseInt(process.env.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT) || 60000);
```

Comment: Where is the support directory? Can you provide an example? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://XXXX), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).